# Getting device make using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How to get the device make of an Android or iPhone using PhoneGap e.g. Samsung, Motorola etc.

Answer (score 3):

// These reference the same `device`

```
var phoneName = device.name;
```

### Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Look at this link for more details.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_device_device.md.html

Comment: device.name does not return manufacturer name. As stated in documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_device_device.md.html it is returning product name which is 'production code name' not model name as user know it :-(

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work
String str = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

Comment: He is talking about using phone gap not native functionality.